# Equation for solving for a variable value of a GLMM probability equation

Tags: mixed-model, linear-algebra

I am trying to solve for a value of x given all the values of the other x's and at a set value for πij.

[image: πij=exp(β0+β1x1ij+β2x2ij+β3x3ij+bi+uj)1+exp(β0+β1x1ij+β2x2ij+β3x3ij+bi+uj)]

For example

.5 = e^(20 + 10(1) + 15(1) + 20(x3) + 3 + 2)/ 1+ e^(20 + 10(1) + 15(1) + 20(x3) + 3 + 2)

How would I rewrite the equation to solve for the value of x3?

Comment: Hey @user158565 can you please describe is the beta just the beta for the variable x3? It doesn't take into account information from all the other variables?

Comment: so in this case when I have a probability of .5 the log of .5/.5 is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\pi \ne 0$ and $\pi \ne 1$
$$\pi = \frac {\exp(X\beta)}{1+\exp(X\beta)}$$
$$\pi ({1+\exp(X\beta)})= {\exp(X\beta)}$$
$$\pi+\pi \exp(X\beta)= {\exp(X\beta)}$$
$$\pi= {\exp(X\beta)} - \pi \exp(X\beta)$$
$$\pi= (1-\pi){\exp(X\beta)} $$
$$\frac {\pi}{1-\pi}= {\exp(X\beta)} $$
$$\log\frac {\pi}{1-\pi}= X\beta $$

In your case,
$$log(0.5/0.5) = 0 =20 + 10(1) + 15(1) + 20(x3) + 3 + 2$$
Then you can get the answer.

Comment: Ah yes but I want to solve for a single x within Xβ given all the other variable coefficients and values and a set probability.

Comment: Another question - when I solve for x3 I get -.25 however when I plug it into the original equation I don't get 0.5 as the probability.

Comment: E^(50+20(-.25)) = e^45

e^45/1 + e^45 = .99

Comment: You should get x3 = -2.75

Comment: Oh yeah oops its actually -2.5